# Stripe subscription: how to discount several next payments?

Tags: stripe-payments

I would like to implement the following referral system in the subscription app:

1. customer (with already active or trialing subscription) generates the promotion code for 20% on first subscription payment for his friends; promotion code is limited in time & unlimited in redemption count
2. every time this promotion code is redeemed by anyone customer who generated the code should receive 20% discount on his next subscription payments, e.g. for 10 redemptions customer should have 20% off on their next 10 payments even if the original promotion code has already expired.

Is there any way to do so?
I can handle webhook calls & store any intermediate data in the DB if needed.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, though the exact implementation of it will fluctuate based on specifics of your use case, primarily whether it is possible for your customers to have more than one Subscription active at a time that should be discounted as part of your step 2.

Setting up a webhook endpoint to listen for related Events is the best approach for being made aware of the use of the Promotion Codes you're generating in step 1. Events with a type of `checkout.session.completed` would be good to listen for to track consumption of your Promotion Codes.  If you've implemented the Customer Portal with Subscription update capabilities and are allowing Promotion Codes to be redeemed there, then you will likely also want to listen for `customer.subscription.updated` Events to detect Customer Portal updates that redeemed a Promotion Code.

For the customer that generated the Promotion Code, if you want their discount to be redeemed on a single Subscription, then using a [Subscription Schedule](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules/use-cases#upgrade-downgrade-coupons) would be a good fit. With that approach you can add the discount to the desired [phases](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules#subscription-schedule-phases), and set the `iterations` of that phase to match the number of redemptions to [control the duration of the phase](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules#phase-length). Additional logic may be required on your end to track the desired number of iterations that should include the discount if the Promotion Code doesn't expire before the end of the current billing period for that Subscription.

If you want to apply the discount across multiple Subscriptions, you will need to add more processing logic to track how many discount redemptions should be provided and how many are remaining. Then you can listen for `invoice.created` Events to track the creation of Invoices for the Customer that should receive the discount, and update those Invoices with a discount if they meet your criteria and the customer still has redemptions remaining.

The question was a bit vague so I made some assumptions about the sections that you were looking for guidance or ideas on, let me and the community know if your question intended to be more targeted about a specific portion of this flow.

Comment: Thank you, looks like Subscription Schedule would do the job. But is it OK to update a phase when one more redemption happens?

Comment: Yes, you can update existing phases to increment their `iterations` value as needed.